# Python - How to sort a list of lists by the fourth element in each list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I would like to sort the following list of lists by the fourth element (the integer) in each individual list.

```
unsorted_list = [['a','b','c','5','d'],['e','f','g','3','h'],['i','j','k','4','m']]
```

How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to sort by the second element, or the fourth?

Answer (score 236):

```
unsorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
```

Comment: It's worth noting that in this method, the integers are lexicographically compared. Thus, `'5'` will be larger than `'20'`. If an integer comparison is to be made, `key=lambda x: int(x[3])` should be used

Comment: You can also use `key=itemgetter(3)` here (from the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) module). While some people find `itemgetter` and `attrgetter` less readable than lambdas, others use them extensively, so it's at least worth being able to read them and know what they do.

Comment: this is the reason why I love python <3

Comment: x = [[[5,3],1.0345],[[5,6],5.098],[[5,4],4.89],[[5,1],5.97]] With a list like this is, how can we sort with respect to elements in x[0][1] ?

Comment: To sort in descending order, add `reverse=True` as a parameter.

Comment: Can also do a multi-sort;
`l = [[0,1,1],[0,2,1],[0,2,2]]`
`l.sort(key=lambda e: e[2], reverse=True)`
`l.sort(key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 73):

Use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with a `key` as follows -

```
>>> unsorted_list = [['a','b','c','5','d'],['e','f','g','3','h'],['i','j','k','4','m']]
>>> sorted(unsorted_list, key = lambda x: int(x[3]))
[['e', 'f', 'g', '3', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', '4', 'm'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '5', 'd']]
```

The `lambda` returns the fourth element of each of the inner lists and the `sorted` function uses that to sort those list. This assumes that `int(elem)` will not fail for the list.

Or use `itemgetter` (As Ashwini's comment pointed out, this method would not work if you have string representations of the numbers, since they are bound to fail somewhere for 2+ digit numbers)

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(unsorted_list, key = itemgetter(3))
[['e', 'f', 'g', '3', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', '4', 'm'], ['a', 'b', 'c', '5', 'd']]
```

Comment: `itemgetter` will not work if the list contains : `[['a','b','c','100','d'],['e','f','g','2','h'],['i','j','k','4','m']]`

Comment: True. Maybe I should just remove it, the `lambda` does the trick here.

Comment: Yes, `itemgetter(3)` only replaces the `lambda x: x[3]`, not `lambda x: int(x[3])`. (You could `compose(int, itemgetter(3))`, but only if you're insane, or really determined to write Haskell or Lisp code in Python…)

Comment: x = [[[5,3],1.0345],[[5,6],5.098],[[5,4],4.89],[[5,1],5.97]] With a list like this is can we sort using itemgetter() with respect to elements in x[0][1] ?